# Why are talend components starting before tParallelize dependencies are complete?

Tags: talend

Why are jobs starting before tParallelize dependencies are complete?

I'm trying to execute SQL statements in parallel, then wait for the first wave to finish before starting the second wave.

The second tParallelize is in place as I have other SQL templates to run in that first wave and want to do them in parallel but have trimmed down the use case for clarity of this post.

[image]

[image]

And here is a simpler case with just tSleep and tWarn components illustrating my question.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option called "Wait for all" in tParallelize component, which will make the process to wait till all the parallel runs has completed its execution. Instead of connecting all the parallel runs to another tParallelize component try using that "Wait for all" link. [image]

Refer: [Link](https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/7.2/orchestration/tparallelize-tmsgbox-parallelizing-synchronizing-subjobs-execution-standard-component-enterprise-the)

Comment: Thank you so much @Aravind30790.  I did not realize - much appreciated.